How can I export PyTorch model to ONNX if it uses PackedSequence?
I try to export PyTorch model that uses PackedSequence into ONNX model and get next error
RuntimeError: ONNX export failed: Cannot export individual pack_padded_sequence or pad_packed_sequence; these operations must occur in pairs.
Sorry for a maybe silly question, but how can I use these operations in pairs?
Code of model:
bn_output_features = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(output_features.to(self.device), origin_nrof_trans, enforce_sorted=False, batch_first=True,)
bn_output_features = self.feature_bn(bn_output_features) # There will new PackedSequence from function below
bn_output_features, _ = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(bn_output_features, batch_first=True)


def forward(self, x):
    return torch.nn.utils.rnn.PackedSequence(data=super().forward(x.data), batch_sizes=x.batch_sizes, sorted_indices=x.sorted_indices,)

Code for export:
torch.onnx.export(model=self.base_rnn,
                args=(features, nrof_trans),
                f="ct4001.onnx",
                export_params=True,
                opset_version=10,
                do_constant_folding=True,
                input_names = ['input_data', 'origin_nrof_trans'],
                output_names = ['output'],
                # dynamic_axes={
                # 'input' : {0 : 'batch_size'},
                # 'output' : {0 : 'batch_size'}
                # }
            )

I tried to decorate pad_packed_sequence, to convert PackedSequence right away, but it doesn't work
def pad_sequence(f, *args, batch_first=False):
    tensor, batch_sz, sorted_inds = None, None, None
    def wrapper():
        nonlocal tensor, batch_sz, sorted_inds
        tensor = args[0].data
        batch_sz = args[0].batch_sizes.
        sorted_inds = args[0].sorted_indices
        return f(*args, batch_first=batch_first)
    return wrapper()[0], tensor, batch_sz, sorted_inds

data, tensor, batch_sz, sorted_inds = pad_sequence(
    nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence, 
    nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(
        output_features.to(self.device), 
        origin_nrof_trans, 
        enforce_sorted=False, batch_first=True,)
    )
bn_output_features = self.feature_bn(tensor, batch_sz, sorted_inds)  # Function below return tensor

def forward(self, data, batch_sz, sorted_inds):
    return pad_sequence(
        nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence,
        nn.utils.rnn.PackedSequence(
            data=super().forward(data), 
            batch_sizes=batch_sz, 
            sorted_indices=sorted_inds,),
        batch_first=True
    )[0]

